# Vue.js3 Passing value from function to label for checkbox input, and have label change based upon the boolean of the checkbox

Tags: vue.js, label, vuejs3

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input @change="change($event)"  type="checkbox" id="check" v-model="checked" class="toggle" />
        <label for="check" >{{ status }}</label>
    </div>

</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
        import { ref } from 'vue'

         interface Props {
            status?: string
        }

        const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
            status: "Locked",
        });

        const checked = ref(false)
        let status = "";

        const change = () => {
            
             if(checked.value === true) {
                    status="Locked"
                } else {
                    status="Unlocked"
                }
                console.log(checked.value, status)
        }
</script>
```

(Using the composition api w/setup) The console.log(checked.value, status) returns the correct information, I just can't figure out how to use status as the label, and have it change when the checkbox is clicked.

Desired action would be:

- checked.value = true; status = "Unlocked" <--to be displayed as label
- checked.value = false; status="Locked" <--to be displayed as label

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: status should be also a reactive variable: `const status = ref("");` and re assign the content via  `status.value = 'locked'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

status should be also a reactive variable:

```js
const status = ref("");
```

and re-assign the content via

```js
status.value = 'locked';
```

keep in mind, that every variable you want to display in your template, has to be reactive.